# Zoho Creator -- Get calendar date from calendar report and paste into another form

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I have a calendar report. when i click on a date, i want a different form to open, not the form that the calendar report is based on. Then i want the date value from the first form to be passed to the second form. So far, I have this code, on load of the Calendar Form:

```
MyDate = input.Departure_Date_Time;
//return same window to calendar report
openUrl("https://app.zohocreator.com/ccimailzoho/interhof-travel- 
calendar#Calendar","same window");
//open trip form in popup
openurl("#Form:Trip_Form","popup window");
//Trip_Form.Departure_Date_Time = MyDate;
```

But it doesn't work; MyDate variable does not hold the value between the two forms. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your question - You are adding code to on Load of form, but you want the action to take place in your report?

Comment: I found a way to make this work. I needed to set my field values in my openurl statement: `openurl("#Form:Trip_Form?Departure_Date_Time=" + input.Departure_Time + "&Arrival_Date_Time=" + input.Departure_Time,"same window");re_Time + "&Arrival_Date_Time=" + input.Departure_Time,"same window");`

Answer (score 2):

For future viewers, if you want to set a value of a form on open from a different form, you can set the value directly in the openurl statement:`openurl("#Form:Trip_Form?Departure_Date_Time=" + input.Departure_Time + "&Arrival_Date_Time=" + input.Departure_Time,"same window");`